# django not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: python-3.x, django

Though I have installed django, when I run django -admin startproject projectfirst, it is showing django is not recognised as internal or external command.

Comment: It is `django-admin` in one word, not `django -admin` (so `-admin` is *not* a flag).

Comment: `django-admin startproject projectfirst` its `django-admin` not `django -admin` (with a space inbetween)